# how to change scrollbar theme in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, scrollbar

Do you know anyway to change the style and theme of a scroll bar in a vb.net application? I need code or program that **changes all scroll bars of the form**.

I've been searching the web and found programs to change color of scroll bar but they were mostly designed for websites and written in CSS or JavaScript code. I would be so thankful if you have a solution for it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There isn't `any` property or feature to change the style of scrollbar of WinForm control. You should have to choose WPF instead of WinForm.